# Objects are not valid as a React child ( found: object with key{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15})

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous, react-hooks, rendering

when i try to update my data i see this bug.

```
const saveResult = async ()=>{
    if(akiec=="" || bcc=="" ||bkl=="" ||df=="" ||melanoma=="" ||nv=="" ||vasc==""){
        alert("Something is empty!!")
    }
    else{
        await setLoading(true)
        await firebase 
        .firestore()
        .collection(`Users/${email}/Results`)
        .doc(`${ID}`) 
        .update({
            akiec : akiec,//state
            bcc : bcc,//state
            bkl : bkl,//state
            df : df,//state
            melanoma : melanoma,//state
            nv : nv,//state
            vasc : vasc,//state
        })
        .then( async() => {
            setLoading(false)
            alert('Updated!')
        });
    }
}
```

And my `useEffect()`

```
const {item, userEmail, id} = route.params


useEffect( ()=>{
    console.log(item)
    setValue(item)      
    setEmail(userEmail)
    setID(id)  
    return () => {
        setAkiec("")
        setBcc("")
        setBkl("")
        setDf("")
        setMelanoma("")
        setNv("")
        setVasc("") 
      };
},[])
const setValue = (item) => {
    setImageURL(item.imageURL)
    setAkiec(item.akiec.toString())
    setBcc(item.bcc.toString())
    setBkl(item.bkl.toString())
    setDf(item.df.toString())
    setMelanoma(item.melanoma.toString())
    setNv(item.nv.toString())
    setVasc(item.vasc.toString())
}
```

I had this bug but I still update successful and I dont know how?

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
> This is my all code in this page.

```
export default function DetailRecord({route, navigation}){
const [ID, setID] = useState("");
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const [imageURL, setImageURL] = useState("");
const [akiec,setAkiec] = useState("")
const [bcc,setBcc] = useState("")
const [bkl,setBkl] = useState("")
const [df,setDf] = useState("")
const [melanoma,setMelanoma] = useState("")
const [nv,setNv] = useState("")
const [vasc,setVasc] = useState("")
const {item, userEmail, id} = route.params


useEffect( ()=>{
    console.log(item)
    setValue(item)      
    setEmail(userEmail)
    setID(id)  
    return () => {
        setAkiec("")
        setBcc("")
        setBkl("")
        setDf("")
        setMelanoma("")
        setNv("")
        setVasc("") 
      };
},[])
const setValue = (item) => {
    setImageURL(item.imageURL)
    setAkiec(item.akiec.toString())
    setBcc(item.bcc.toString())
    setBkl(item.bkl.toString())
    setDf(item.df.toString())
    setMelanoma(item.melanoma.toString())
    setNv(item.nv.toString())
    setVasc(item.vasc.toString())
}
const saveResult = async ()=>{
    if(akiec=="" || bcc=="" ||bkl=="" ||df=="" ||melanoma=="" ||nv=="" ||vasc==""){
        alert("Something is empty!!")
    }
    else{
        await setLoading(true)
        await firebase 
        .firestore()
        .collection(`Users/${email}/Results`)
        .doc(`${ID}`) 
        .update({
            akiec : akiec,//state
            bcc : bcc,//state
            bkl : bkl,//state
            df : df,//state
            melanoma : melanoma,//state
            nv : nv,//state
            vasc : vasc,//state
        })
        .then( async() => {
            setLoading(false)
            alert('Updated!')
        });
    }
}
if(loading){
    return <Loading />;
}
return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <SafeAreaView />
        <View style={styles.header}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.backIcon} onPress={()=>{
                navigation.goBack()
                }} >
                <MaterialIcons name="keyboard-backspace" size={35} color="black" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.saveIcon} onPress={()=>{
                saveResult()
                }} >
                <MaterialIcons name="save-alt" size={35} color="black" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Image source={{uri: imageURL}} style={styles.image} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.footer}>
            <View style={styles.trendContainer}>
                <View>
                    <Text style={styles.trendText}>The proportion of diseases</Text>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <MaterialIcons name="add-to-queue" size={25} />
                </View>
            </View>
            <ScrollView 
                style={styles.scrollView}
                contentContainerStyle={styles.contentScrollView}
            >
                <View style={styles.typeWrapper}>
                    <FormInput
                        labelName={"Intraepithelial Carcinoma"}
                        value={akiec}
                        autoCapitalize="none"
                        onChangeText={(value) => setAkiec(value)}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.typeWrapper}>
                    <FormInput
                        labelName={"Basal Cell Carcinoma"}
                        value={bcc}
                        autoCapitalize="none"
                        onChangeText={(value) => setBcc(value)}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.typeWrapper}>
                    <FormInput
                        labelName={"Benign Keratosis-like Lesions"}
                        value={bkl}
                        autoCapitalize="none"
                        onChangeText={(value) => setBkl(value)}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.typeWrapper}>
                    <FormInput
                        labelName={"Dermatofibroma"}
                        value={df}
                        autoCapitalize="none"
                        onChangeText={(value) => setDf(value)}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.typeWrapper}>
                    <FormInput
                        labelName={"Melanoma"}
                        value={melanoma}
                        autoCapitalize="none"
                        onChangeText={(value) => setMelanoma(value)}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.typeWrapper}>
                    <FormInput
                        labelName={"Melanocytic Nevus"}
                        value={nv}
                        autoCapitalize="none"
                        onChangeText={(value) => setNv(value)}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.typeWrapper}>
                    <FormInput
                        labelName={"Vascular Lesions"}
                        value={vasc}
                        autoCapitalize="none"
                        onChangeText={(value) => setVasc(value)}
                    />
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    </View>
);
```

}

And my data on firestore
[image]

Comment: It seems that this error is while rendering new data not while saving. can you provide more codes or data about error ?

Comment: of course i just edited my post, please check it again